# about the creation of topic in combination with authorization in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, authorization, activemq-classic

I want to separate the creation of topic and writing to topic. That's to say, one application is responsible for creating topic and I give it the "admin" of topic, another application which is the publisher is responsible **only** for writing to that topic, thus I only give the publisher the right of "write".

But it seems to be not working because `Topic topic = session.createTopic(topic_name)` requires the publisher to have the "admin" authorization.

So is there any way to solve this problem?